# What is the equivalent of MS Access InStr function in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, ms-access

This query runs in Access 2013 but I need it converted to SQL Server 2008. The issue is that the `INSTR()` function does not exist in SQL Server and the query references the field generated in same query `EXPR1`.

How would this be changed over to SQL Server 2008?

```
SELECT PartID, Description, Service, 
InStr(1,[Description]," ") AS Expr1, 
Left([Description],[Expr1]) AS part
FROM TI
WHERE (((PartID) Is Not Null) AND ((Service)="JTP"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InStr` is pretty similar to `CHARINDEX`. So, your query can be written as:

```
SELECT  PartID, 
        [Description], 
        [Service], 
        CHARINDEX(' ',[Description]) Expr1,
        LEFT([Description],CHARINDEX(' ',[Description])) Part
FROM TI
WHERE PartID IS NOT NULL 
AND [Service] = 'JTP';
```